# Question of the... Month!

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week, question-of-the-month

Yeah, you heard right, it's coming back!
It's been almost three years since the last time time Question of the Week was featured on the blog (#46) and 
it's about time that it came back!

We (the Super User blog editors) have decided that we weren't able to manage it weekly so now its a monthly. 
That's pretty much the only thing that's changed.

**The rules are the same:**

Please post any questions that you feel is of worth and the reason why.

Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake.

If you like a posted question then vote it up.

**Don't Downvote**: Upvote the ones you like up but let the others be...

When submitting a QotM, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog.
 This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say 
 something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody 
 interested in writing the article.

Each month we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

*Nominations for #1 start on Monday, 11th April 2016*

---

The blog editors can be found at [Super User Blog Editor Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/356/super-user-blog-editor-room)

Comment: Just as an FYI, this is an informational post.  We'll be starting the QOTM nominations on the 11th.

Comment: 2016 #1: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11417/question-of-the-month-1-april-16